# Proving a set is a subset of a union with itself and another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A and B be sets. Show that
$$\space A \subseteq (A \cup B)$$

My proof is as follows, but I don't feel confident that what I've done is correct. Any input is much appreciated.

$$x \in A \cup B \equiv x \in A \wedge x \in B \equiv x \in A$$

Therefore, A is a subset of the union of A and B.

Comment: one major mistake I see in the proof is you have a logical AND where it should be an OR

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look closely at your argument: it implies that $x\in A\cup B$ if and only if $x\in A$, which is clearly not the case in general. For instance, if $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{1\}$, then $1\in A\cup B$, but $1\notin A$.

You’re starting in the wrong place. To show that $X\subseteq Y$, you need to show that every member of $X$ is a member of $Y$. To do this you don’t start with an arbitrary member of $Y$: some of them may not be in $X$. You start with an arbitrary member of $X$ and try to show that it must belong to $Y$. Here you want to show that $A\subseteq A\cup B$, so you should be starting with an arbitrary member of $A$. And when you do that, the rest of the argument is trivial: if $x\in A$, then it’s certainly true that $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, which is what it means to say that $x\in A\cup B$.

If you insist on doing the argument with formal logical expressions, what you want is $$x\in A\to(x\in A\lor x\in B)\leftrightarrow x\in A\cup B\;.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: notice $$(x\in A\lor x\in B)\leftrightarrow x\in A\cup B\;$$ by using this logical statement $$p\Rightarrow p \lor q$$ we have  $$x\in A\Rightarrow (x\in A\lor x\in B).$$

Comment: How do we know $p\Rightarrow p \lor q$ is true. Is it an axiom or definition? Yes, it is intuitively true, but that makes it harder to ask "why is it true". My own guess at an answer would be that the truth depends on the definition of disjunction.

Answer (score 2):

You're going in the wrong direction. Don't assume $x\in A\cup B$, assume $x\in A$: you want to show that each element in $A$ is also an element of $A\cup B$ (not vice versa). Also, $x\in A\cup B\iff x\in A\textrm{ OR (not and) }x\in B$.

Let $x\in A$, and note that $x\in A\cup B\implies x\in A$ or $x\in B$. But, as $x\in A$, $x\in A\cup B$. Therefore, each element of $A$ is an element of $A\cup B$, so that $A\subseteq A\cup B$.

However, you should note that your proof is the correct proof of $A\cap B\subseteq A$ if you replace your $A\cup B$ with $A\cap B$.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of argument is best written out in plain language, with minimal use of symbols.

Suppose $x\in A$. That is, $x$ is an element of $A$. Then certainly $x$ is either an element of $A$ or an element of $B$ (or both). Thus $x$ is an element of $A\cup B$, ie. $x\in A\cup B$.

Since we have shown that any element of $A$ is an element of $A\cup B$, $A\subseteq A\cup B$.